# SOAP web service and JSON responce in android

Tags: android, json

I need to call SOAP based web service in android . I use following code . but it does not call because it gives response in json format . SO how can i do it ??

Is there any help ??

```
public void callsoapservice() {
    final String METHOD_NAME = "GetLoginString";
    final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetLoginString";
    final String NAMESPACE = " http://tempuri.org/";
    final String URL = "http://209.139.209.216/STMobileWS/MobileWebservice/STOlogin.asmx?WSDL";

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    request.addProperty("sCompanyCode", "659");
    request.addProperty("sUserName", "Chad12345");
    request.addProperty("sPassword", "chad");

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope( SoapEnvelope.VER12 );

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        // SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;

         System.out.println("Received :" + envelope.bodyIn.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        System.out.println("EEEEEEEEE  " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what problem you are getting in the response?

Comment: I got error at line "androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);".

Comment: I have solved this issue using HTTP post service .

Comment: I'm closing this out, as you have solved your issue.

Comment: You are using the local URL otherwise I can put here an complete answer to how to use it.